# Why does shrinking stop once one of the terms is fully shrunk

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm looking at the comments in [`shrink`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.6/QuickCheck-2.13.2/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:shrink):

> It is tempting to write the last line as `[Branch x' l' r' | x' <- shrink x, l' <- shrink l, r' <- shrink r]` but this is the wrong thing! It will force QuickCheck to shrink `x`, `l` and `r` in tandem, and shrinking will stop once one of the three is fully shrunk.

I'm a bit puzzled about this, I thought that the problem with that shrink was that we're taking the cartesian product of the shrinks of the subterms, which might be quite large. I don't get why shrinking will stop once one of the three is fully shrunk.

So in other words, I thought the definition above would compute all combinations of shrinks of `x`, `l`, and `r`, but I wouldn't expect shrink to stop once one the the terms is fully shrunk.

Comment: Yeah agree, maybe it's a typo and they meant `[Branch x' l' r' | x' <- shrink x | l' <- shrink l | r' <- shrink r]` back when parallel list comprehensions were in vogue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed code *is* wrong, because we only consider shrinks that shrink all three of the terms by at least one step. To see the problem, imagine all three candidates are `Int`:

```
x = 1
l = 0
r = 2
```

Then we have

```
shrink x = [0]
shrink l = []
shrink r = [1, 0]
```

A nested list comprehension over these three lists will yield no values, because no suitable candidate for `l` can be found. So we never try some valid shrinks like `(0, 0, 1)`. The `shrink` instance for tuples does the right thing (suggesting each shrink where *at least one* term can be shrunk), so mapping over that solves the problem.

Comment: I see, so maybe the comment should be rephrased to say that shrinking *could* stop if one of the three is fully shrink (and not *once*), or something like that...

Comment: I mean, even if it's not the case that one is fully shrunk, we skip over some valid shrinks. Imagine (1, 1, 1): there are 7 valid shrinks, but a nested list comprehension over the three shrinks misses stuff like (1, 0, 1), yielding only (0, 0, 0).

Comment: @DamianNadales 1. No, shrinking _will definitely_ stop if one of the components is fully shrunk, as it says. Because then you have something like `[... | x' <- [], ...]` and this is always empty. 2. "and not once" Here "once" means "as soon as", not "one time".

Comment: Also see the [`successors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/successors) package, which gives you an functor to model that “one step in one field” idea.